# Dictionary not deserializing

Tags: c#, serialization, binary

I'm having a problem where one Dictionary in my project is either not serializing or not deserializing. After deserializing, the data I serialized is simply not in the object.

Here's the relevant snip of the class being serialized:

```
class Person : ISerializable {
    private Dictionary<Relation,List<int>> Relationships = new Dictionary<Relation,List<int>>();

    public Person(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {
        this.Relationships = (Dictionary<Relation, List<int>>) info.GetValue("Relationships", typeof(Dictionary<Relation, List<int>>));
        }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {
        info.AddValue("Relationships", this.Relationships);
        }
    }
```

Note, this is binary serialization. Everything else in the project serializes and deserialzes correctly.

Comment: You need a default constructor. I assume you have one otherwise how can this work at all? How do you know that you object does not contain any data when it has no public accessors? Is there a lot of code you're not showing us for simplicity? The error might be there.

Comment: Couple of questions: 1. the class is not adorned with the [Serializable] attribute, is this a typo?  2. Are there reasons why you are using the ISerializable interface that we cannot see because of your code snippet pruning?  For simple serialization this interface (and the associated method and constructor) are not necesseary.

Comment: You could also look into the DataContractSerializer in .Net 3.5 which should serialize a Dictionary<> just fine.

Comment: Regarding all the missing things- I have them - I only included things here that seemed relevant. The attribute was an oversight on my part.

Comment: @Paul - Removing the ISerializable interface and commenting the related code did not hurt my problem, nor did it help it.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    [Serializable]
    class Relation
    {
    }

    [Serializable]
    class Person
    {
        private Dictionary<Relation, List<int>> Relationships = new Dictionary<Relation, List<int>>();

        public Person() {}

        public void AddRelationship() {
            Relationships.Add(new Relation(), new List<int>());
        }

        public int CountRelations()
        {
            return Relationships.Count;
        }

        /*
        public Person(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            this.Relationships = (Dictionary<Relation, List<int>>)info.GetValue("Relationships", typeof(Dictionary<Relation, List<int>>));
        }

        public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            info.AddValue("Relationships", this.Relationships);
        }
         * */
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.AddRelationship();
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, person);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        person = (Person)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        Console.WriteLine("Count: " + person.CountRelations());
    }
}
```

Note: the second constructor and the GetObjectData are not required, although adding them doesn't break anything either. If I am oversimplifying your code, perhaps you can post a modified version of some working, runnable code that demonstrates the failure you are observing. You can either remove things from your code until it's simple enough to post a compiling version without requiring external classes, or add things to mine until it reproduces the error - whichever is easier for you.

You may also find that in the process of making a simple runnable version that reproduces the error, that you are able to solve the problem yourself.